# Determine/obtain/find management chain (hierarchy) for employees using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table (in an MS Access DB) with every employee at a company. The table also has a column to indicate each employee's manager. There are columns (with no data) to indicate that employee's full management chain to the CEO. I need to determine/obtain/find and fill this data using SQL (and/or VBA).

I know what needs to be done but I'm drawing a complete blank on how to do it efficiently.

I know I could go row by row but that seems so inefficient. There has to be a better way.

For example, take this table below:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| employeeID | managerID | manager1 | manager2 | manager3 |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| a          |           |          |          |          |
| b          | a         |          |          |          |
| c          | a         |          |          |          |
| d          | a         |          |          |          |
| e          | b         |          |          |          |
| f          | b         |          |          |          |
| g          | c         |          |          |          |
| h          | c         |          |          |          |
| i          | d         |          |          |          |
| j          | e         |          |          |          |
| k          | f         |          |          |          |
| l          | g         |          |          |          |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

- `a` has no manager (CEO)
- `b`'s manager is `a`
- `l`'s manager is `g` whose manager is `c` whose manager is `a`
- etc...

So this would result in the table:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| employeeID | managerID | manager1 | manager2 | manager3 |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| a          |           |          |          |          |
| b          | a         | a        |          |          |
| c          | a         | a        |          |          |
| d          | a         | a        |          |          |
| e          | b         | a        | b        |          |
| f          | b         | a        | b        |          |
| g          | c         | a        | c        |          |
| h          | c         | a        | c        |          |
| i          | d         | a        | d        |          |
| j          | e         | a        | b        | e        |
| k          | f         | a        | b        | f        |
| l          | g         | a        | c        | g        |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: How many levels can the management chain have?  Note that Access does not support recursive queries, so you are probably looking at doing some number of self joins.

Comment: A max of 15. I don't mind running multiple self-joins but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why fill in the rest of the columns?  Your table is normalized *now* - filling in the other 3 columns will de-normalize it. The fact that you would essentially be copying data into different places in the table should illustrate that, and the resulting schema will be an absolute nightmare to maintain referential integrity in. By all means make the query, but use it as a view - NOT to fill the table in.

Comment: There are half a million records in the table. I suspect I will need many views and they will be hella complex/slow. For the sake of speed I figure I can just update the table. If the views are not complex then I will definitely just use views and not make updates to the table.

Comment: More records = more of a referential integrity problem.  What happens when you need to update a position in the hierarchy? Even with your current layout that's a hassle for key changes and deletes. Expanding the number of fields compounds the issue.  If you don't have a plan for maintaining data integrity, you're setting yourself up to trash the data in your table.

Comment: The `employeeID` and `managerID` fields would be changed once a month and the rest of the fields would be updated at the same time. Keep in mind, this is not the SOR for the company. I'm getting the `employeeID` and `managerID` data from the SOR and trying to calculate the rest. I only need this for a project that'll be done in 5 months.